# How to use Python Seaborn Visualizations in PowerPoint?

Tags: python, dynamic, powerpoint, seaborn, figure

I created some figures with Seaborn in a Jupyter Notebook. I would now like to present those figures in a PowerPoint presentation.

I know that it is possible to export the figures as png and include them in the presentation. But then they would be static, and if something changes in the dataframe, the picture would be the same. Is there an option to have a dynamic figure in PowerPoint? Something like a small Jupyter Notebook you could Display in the slides?

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Anaconda Fusion](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/fusion/) (also the [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBHf1PLzLvg)), which let's you use Python inside of Excel. This could possibly work since you can link figures/data elements between Excel and PowerPoint (but special restrictions might apply when the figure is created via Python rather than standard Excel). Anaconda Fusion is free to try for a couple of months.

Another solution would be to use the [Jupyter Notebook to create your presentation instead of PowerPoint](https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67). Go to `View -> Cell Toolbar -> Slideshow`and you can choose which code cells should become slides.

A third approach would be to create an animation of the figure as the data frame changes and then include the animation (GIF or video) in PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joel.

I am working for a Company which wants to use their corporate slides and think-cell addins so just creating a slideshow from Jupyter is not an Option.

I will try Anaconda Fusion.

Answer (score 2):

The following procedures probably won't be the most elegant solution, but it will let you produce a Seaborn plot, store it as an image file, and export the same image to an open powerpoint presentation. Depending on whether you set `LinkToFile` to `True` or `False`, the images will or will not update when the source changes. I'm messing around with this using cells in Spyder, but it should work in a Jupyter notebook as well. Make sure that you have a folder named `c:\pptSeaborn\`.

Here it is:

```
# Some imports
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import win32com.client
import win32api

os.chdir('C:/pptSeaborn')

# Settings for some random data
mu = 0
sigma = 1
simulation = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10)

# Make seaborn plot from simulated data. Save as image file.
def SeabornPlot(data, filename = 'c:\\pptSeaborn\\snsPlot.png'):    
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data, shade=True)
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 440)
    plt.close(fig)

# Import image file to active powerpoint presentation
def SeabornPPT(plotSource, linkImage):

    Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    Presentation = Application.Activepresentation
    slidenr = Presentation.Slides.Count + 1
    Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(slidenr, 12)
    gph = Base.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName=plotSource, 
                                     LinkToFile=linkImage, SaveWithDocument=True, 
                                     Left=50, Top=25, Width=800, Height=500)
    Presentation.slides(slidenr).select()

# Produce data, save plot as image, and export image to powerpoint
SeabornPlot(data = simulation)
SeabornPPT(plotSource = 'c:\\pptSeaborn\\snsPlot.png', linkImage = False)
```

Now, if you have an open powerpoint presentation and run this whole thing five times, you will get somthing like this:

[image]

If you go ahead and save this somewhere, and reopen it, it will still look the same.

Now you can set `linkImage = True`, and run the whole thing five times again. Depending on the random data generated, you will still get five slides with different graphs.

[image]

But NOW, if you save the presentation and reopen it, all plots will look the same because they're linked to the same image file:

[image]

The next step could be to wrap the whole thing into a function that takes filename and LinkToFile as arguments. You could also include whether or not the procedure makes a new slide each time an image is exported. I hope you find my sggestion useful. I liked your question, and I'm hoping to see a few other suggestions as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and give some Feedback on it =)

Comment: Any success with this suggestion, or did you find an other approach?

Comment: We went with another idea. You can save the figures as a .png file and insert this into Powerpoint. There is an Option when inserting it, that the Picture will be updated every time you open PowerPoint, retrivining a new version of the file from the Folder I saved it to. So when I make changes in Seaborn, a new version of the file is automatically saved as a Picture which will then be updated in PowerPoint.

Comment: Nice template for using PowerPoint via win32com.

Answer (score 2):

We now went with this approach:

You can save the figures as a .png file and insert this into Powerpoint. There is an Option when inserting it, that the Picture will be updated every time you open PowerPoint, retrivining a new version of the file from the Folder I saved it to. So when I make changes in Seaborn, a new version of the file is automatically saved as a Picture which will then be updated in PowerPoint.